# why it is showing error 'ERROR in Tried to find bootstrap code in angular6?

Tags: angular, command-line-interface

When i need to open my angular project by using the command ng serve --open in cli. it is showing error 'ERROR in Tried to find bootstrap code,but could not. Specify either statically analyzable bootstrap code or pass in an entryModule to the plugins options.
'

Comment: You need to check, are you calling platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule); in main.ts file

Comment: yes i am calling it. the code is below

Comment: platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.log(err));

Comment: post your main.ts code

Comment: import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.log(err));

Comment: please check the question once more. i had added a photo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure your main.ts have the exact following code:

```
import { enableProdMode } from "@angular/core";
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic";

import { AppModule } from "./app/app.module";
import { environment } from "./environments/environment";

if (environment.production) {
    enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: cannot find app/app.module in main.ts showing the error line like this in main.ts

Comment: well you have app.module.ts inside app folder right ? if yes please share the content of app.module.ts

Answer (score -1):

Please check if you have included the required bootstrap modules in the `EntryModule` configuration of your application root module. Also, remember to include the style and js related files in your `angular.json` or `.angular-cli.json` depending on the version of angular you are using. Hope it helps.

Comment: i had called the platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule); in main.ts file.

Comment: Can you please specify if you are using angular version below 6 or above 6 ?

Comment: i am using angular6

Comment: Angular CLI: 6.1.5

Comment: For angular 6 please check if you have included the bootstrap js files inside the `scripts` array in `angular.json` file.

Comment: DOWNVOTED until an example of including "the bootstrap js files inside the scripts array" is provided. The description, alone, is insufficient. Will upvote once provided.